# Suma y promedio de posiciones pares en un vector

Tags: java, array

Realizo un programa que tiene como finalidad sumar las posiciones pares del vector(ojo, no los números pares que se encuentren en el vector, si no las posiciones pares, ejemplo, 0, 2, 4, los cuales hace referencia a un numero cualquiera)

Me he venido arriba con el código, pero algo se me escapa, y cuando intento desplegar solo la suma de dichas posiciones, no obtengo nada ¿Que está pasando?
dejo mi código:

```
public double Mediapar()
{
    for(int i=0; i<c;i++)
    {  
        if(i%2==0)
        {
           cont2++; 
           mediap+= vf[i];
        }

    }
    s2= mediap/cont2;
    return mediap ;
}
```

Espero me puedan guiar de antemano, estoy desesperado, y no se que falla...

Answer (score 1):

!Buenas!

Respondiendo a tu pregunta:

> Realizo un programa que tiene como finalidad sumar las posiciones
>   pares del vector(ojo, no los números pares que se encuentren en el
>   vector, si no las posiciones pares, ejemplo, 0, 2, 4, los cuales hace
>   referencia a un numero cualquiera).

Se puede realizar de la siguiente manera:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numeros [] = {1,2,5,10,20,45,46,80}; //VECTOR DE NUMEROS.

        int sumaTotal = 0; //CONTADOR INICIADO A CERO.

        for(int i=0; i<numeros.length;i++)
        {  
            if(i%2==0) //VERIFICAMOS SI LA POCISION i ES PAR O NO.
            {
               sumaTotal = sumaTotal + numeros[i]; //SUMAMOS VALOR DE i A CONTADOR
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Suma total: " + sumaTotal);
    }
}
```

En caso de querer añadir funcionalidad nueva, o hacer algún otro cambio, creo que el código es sencillo y se puede ver clara la lógica utilizada.

En caso de que no entiendas algo, o necesites ayuda, **coméntame** y edito :)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero lo que yo estoy buscando, es que luego de identificar las posiciones pares del vector, sumar el valor que se encuentre dentro, y eso es lo que yo no consigo

Comment: He editado, mira a ver si eso es lo que buscas. Un saludo

Comment: No, aun asi no era lo que buscaba, pero ya lo resolvi, edito, y adjunto la solución.

Comment: @AxwellDuarte entonces deberías reformular la pregunta, porque ese código hace exactamente lo que tu pides en ella y en comentarios.

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que mediap es la suma de los valores que se encuentran en las posiciones pares del vector, suponiendo que s2 es la media del sumatorio de estos valores, suponiendo que c es el length del vector, suponiendo que vf es el vector y suponiendo que cont2 es el número de veces que encuentra una posición par.

He probado tu código y funciona a la perfección. He añadido la declaración de las variables, así que el fallo puede ser que no hayas declarado alguna de las variables correctamente. Puedes probarlo de este modo para que veas que funciona:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mediapar();
    }

    public static double Mediapar() {
        int vf[] = { 3, 13, 46, 82, 12, 32, 6, 2, 12, 94, 33 };
        int cont2 = 0;
        int mediap = 0;
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < vf.length; i++) {
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    cont2++;
                    mediap += vf[i];
                }
            }
            int s2 = mediap / cont2;
            return mediap;
        }
    }
```

Como te han dicho en los comentarios, puedes refactorizar el código iterando i+= 2, ya que sólo te interesan los índices pares, así no deberás comprobar si se trata de una posición par o no y recorrerás el vector en la mitad de tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

### Con tu método

Necesitas un acumulador para ir sumando los números pares. Tú lo haces en `mediap`. Lo que no se ve en tu código es de dónde sacas la variable `vf`. Tampoco se ve qué es `c`. Que debería ser la longitud del vector.

Luego, tienes un contador `cont2` para saber por cuánto dividir y sacar la media. Eso está bien, otra forma de hacerlo es redondear hacia arriba el resultado de dividir la longitud del vector entre dos (de 5 elementos, 3 son pares, si empiezas a contar desde 0 y 0 es par, que es lo que tú estás suponiendo).

```java
public static double mediaPar(int[] numeros) {
    double acumulador = 0;

    if (numeros.length < 1) { // Si el array esta vacío, devolvemos 0.
        return 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            acumulador += numeros[i];
        }
    }
    return acumulador / Math.ceil(numeros.length / 2.0);
}

public static void main(String args[]) { 
    int arr[] = { 3, 1, 2, 5, 4 };

    mediaPar(arr); // Devuelve 3
}
```

### La opción más corta

La opción más corta, pero que no tiene nada que ver con lo que tienes sería algo así:

```java
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public static double mediaPar(int[] numeros) {
    int acumulado = IntStream.range(0, numeros.length).filter(i -> i % 2 == 0).map(i -> numeros[i]).sum();
    return (acumulado / Math.ceil(numeros.length / 2d));
}
```

La primera línea de la función crea un `IntStream` de números de 0 hasta el índice máximo de tu array de números. Los filtra con `filter` se queda solo con los pares. Ahora con los índices pares hace un mapeo (`map`) para quedarse con los números de posiciones pares de tu array, y los suma con `sum`. Ahora solo queda devolver esa suma entre la mitad del número de elementos de tu lista redondeado hacia arriba (`acumulado / Math.ceil(numeros.length / 2d))`)

---

### Nota sobre las "posiciones pares"

Algo que hay que tener en cuenta es cómo contamos números pares. ¿Contamos por el índice? ¿O por el número de elemento?

```
+--------+-------------+----------+
| Índice | Nº Elemento | Elemento |
+--------+-------------+----------+
|   0    |     1       |     5    |
|   1    |     2       |    15    |
|   2    |     3       |     3    |
|   3    |     4       |     7    |
+--------+-------------+----------+
```

En esa tabla de arriba, si los partes se cuentan por el índice, entonces el resultado es: `(5 + 3) / 2 = 4`. Pero si los pares son por número de elemento, entonces sería: `(15 + 7) / 2 = 11`.

Si fuera por número de elemento la condición a cumplir sería `if (i % 2 == 1)` o `if ((i + 1) % 2 == 0)`

Comment: "Algo que hay que tener en cuenta es cómo contamos números pares. ¿Contamos por el índice? ¿O por el número de elemento?" - en su pregunta dice "posición", que es lo mismo que índice.

Comment: @PrettyAvocado No estoy de acuerdo en que "posición" sea lo mismo que "índice". En el array `[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]`, ¿qué número está en la primera posición? Creo que la respuesta es 1, que sin embargo está en el índice 0. Usar "posición" en lugar de "índice" puede ser confuso. Afortunadamente lo aclara con el ejemplo de "0, 2, 4". Pero creo que merece la pena dejar la nota ahí.

Comment: El ejercicio que me plantearon escribia textuamente posiciones, pero gracias a su aclaración veo que a lo que realmente se referia es al indice, muchas gracias por el dato, soy principiante, aun tengo mucho que aprender.

Comment: @ArianJM te equivocas, en la documentación oficial de Oracle utilizan indiferentemente índice y posición, no hacen ningún tipo de distinción. En este contexto, posición es lo mismo que índice. Por ejemplo, el método get de ArrayList dice: get(int index): Returns the element at the specified position in this List. 
Aquí tienes la fuente: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: @PrettyAvocado curioso... tienes razón. A mi me suena más confuso mezclarlos, pero bueno, es lo que hay.

Answer (score -1):

Lo he resuelto yo mismo, comparto el código por si alguien lo pueda necesitar.

```
public double Mediapar(String vect)
{
    suma=0;
    s=0;
    int aux=0;

    String []o= vect.split(",");

    for(int i=0; i<o.length;i++)
    {
        if(i%2==0)
        {
            p= new double[o.length];
            p[i]=Integer.parseInt(o[i]);
            s += p[i]; 
            i++;
            aux++;
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
        }     
    }
    suma = s / aux;

    return suma;
}
```

Comment: Cuidado con hacer incrementos de `i` dentro del bucle, ya que tal cual como lo tienes, en el for puedes cambiar el `i++` por `i+=2` y eliminar los `i++` dentro del bucle. Luego no le veo el sentido a la creación de `p` cuando luego se lo sumas a `s`. Se puede reemplazar las tres lineas por -> `s+=Integer.parseInt(o[i]);`

Comment: Buena sugerencia, soy principiante aun, y no tengo mucha experiencia, y es lo que me habia funcionado, lo tomare en cuenta, gracias!